# How is the "proportional" calculated in Bayes theorem?

Tags: self-study, bayesian, likelihood

I am struggling with the [Wikipedia entry on Likelihood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood_function).

In an example it mentions $L(P_H = 0.5 |HH) = 0.25$

It mentions that

> Bayes' theorem implies that the posterior probability is proportional
> to the likelihood times the prior probability.

I am trying to understand, in our scenario, what the prior and the post should be. I thought of

post = prior * likelihood = 0.5 * 0.25 = 0.125

This seems way too small.  How is the "proportional" calculated?

Comment: There is a normalizing factor you've forgotten.

Comment: Have you read the Wikipedia entry on Bayes' Theorem?

Comment: @Sycorax thanks I am reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem

Comment: I cant see any mention of a normalizing factor.

Comment: In $P(A|B) = P(B|A) P(A)/P(B)$ the denominator $P(B)$ is the normalizing constant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you multiply a prior probability distribution by the likelihood function you can get a distribution that has an integral of more or less than one. It is not a probability distribution until you scale it to get that integral back to one.